# Hibernate Field Annotaion Behaviour

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Please help me to understand why hibernate field based annotation works based on the primarykey field?.
*Model Class 1* takes `docnum` field value from getter and *Model Class 2* too.Inspite of both places only `docnum` is annotated based on the getter only.It works based on `id` field which is having annotaion in field of *Model Class 2* and  in *Model Class 1* based on getter.

**Model Class 1:**

```
@Entity(name="RDT_ORDER")
public class Order {

private int id;
private String docnum;

@Id
@Column(name="ORDID")    
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@Column(name="ORD_DOCNUM")
public String getDocnum() {
    return docnum+" getter";
}
public void setDocnum(String docnum) {
    this.docnum = docnum;
}
}
```

**Model Class 2:**

```
@Entity(name="RDT_ORDER")
public class Order {

private int id;
private String docnum;

@Id
@Column(name="ORDID")    
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@Column(name="ORD_DOCNUM")
public String getDocnum() {
    return docnum+" getter";
}
public void setDocnum(String docnum) {
    this.docnum = docnum;
}
}
```

**Output :table(RDT_ORDER) values**

```
ID       DOCNUM
5       docnum5 
6       docnum6 getter
```

Comment: you pasted 2 times the same entity.

Comment: Because they designed it like this. The access type is the same for all the entity fields/properties, and it's decided based on where the annotation on the ID is placed. It's a rule, and you simply need to follow it, by placing your annotations consistently on getters, or consistently on fields.

Comment: @dognose Thanks for reply I updated.